# How do I take a user input in bat script?

Tags: batch-file

Basically I have 12 files in my folder and for each of them, a month's name is a suffix. First 3 characters. The user will enter the month, which will be stored in a variable, concatenated with other characters to form a file name and that file will be selected for execution.

Answer (score 2):

The most basic way to get input is to do this:

```
set /P var123="Enter some value: "
```

Then, you can use to variable `var123` like this:

```
echo %var123%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set /p "var=user prompt text "
echo %var%
```

is the usual way. The downside is that the variable's contents are quite difficult to correctly verify since your users may type anything in response. Observe also that `set /p` will not change the value of `var` id <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone is pressed. It is normal to clear `var` first with `set "var="` or it can be used as a default selection with `set "var=default"`. In fact,

```
set "var=default"
set /p "var=[%var%] "
```

can be used to prompt with the default value.

Another approach is by using `choice`

```
echo 1. January
...
echo 9. September
echo o. October
echo n. November
echo d. December

choice /C 123456789ond
```

will set `errorlevel` to 1 to 12 depending on which choice was made.

(There are other options - see `choice /?` from the prompt)

The advantage of this method is that it will only react to one of the listed choices, entry is just 1 key, and you can also specify a default to be chosen if the user does not respond within a programmable time.

Answer (score 1):

This batch file uses the command **CHOICE** if available (Windows Vista and newer Windows versions, Windows Server 2003 and newer Windows Server versions) or command **SET** with option `/P` to prompt the user for one of the twelve months.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
echo(
echo    1 ... January
echo    2 ... February
echo    3 ... March
echo    4 ... April
echo    5 ... May
echo    6 ... June
echo    7 ... July
echo    8 ... August
echo    9 ... September
if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe (
    echo    O ... October
    echo    N ... November
    echo    D ... December
) else (
    echo   10 ... October
    echo   11 ... November
    echo   12 ... December
)
echo(
if not exist %SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe goto MonthPrompt
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 123456789OND /N /M "Please select month:"
set "Month=%Errorlevel%"
goto GetMonth

:MonthPrompt
set "Month="
set /P "Month=Please select month: "
rem Prompt the user again if nothing input by the user.
if not defined Month goto MonthPrompt
rem Remove all double quotes.
set "Month=%Month:"=%"
rem Prompt the user again if just double quotes were input by the user.
if not defined Month goto MonthPrompt
rem Prompt the user again if user input contains a non-digit character.
for /F delims^=0123467890^ eol^= %%I in ("%Month%") do goto MonthPrompt
rem Remove all leading zeros.
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%I in ("%Month%") do set "Month=%%I"
rem Prompt the user again if user input was just one or more 0.
if not defined Month goto MonthPrompt
rem Prompt the user again if input number is greater than 12.
if %Month% GTR 12 goto MonthPrompt

:GetMonth
for %%I in ("1 JAN" "2 FEB" "3 MAR" "4 APR" "5 MAY" "6 JUN" "7 JUL" "8 AUG" "9 SEP" "10 OCT" "11 NOV" "12 DEC") do for /F "tokens=1,2" %%J in (%%I) do if %%J == %Month% set "Month=%%K" & goto BuildFileName

:BuildFileName
echo Selected month: %Month%

endlocal
```

The command **CHOICE** is preferred on being available as it is designed for a choice menu. The user cannot input something unwanted by batch script author and so the evaluation of the user choice is simple by using the exit code of `choice.exe` assigned to the variable `errorlevel`.

The usage of command **SET** with option `/P` as required on Windows XP and former Windows versions is more problematic as the user has the freedom to input any string, from an empty string to a string which could cause malicious code execution on batch script author does not prevent that. There are lots of additional commands necessary to safely make sure that the user has really input a number in range `1` to `12`.

The same batch script above with using just **CHOICE** which means no compatibility with Windows XP (except `choice.exe` from Windows Server 2003 is copied to Windows XP system directory) and even older Windows versions.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
echo(
echo    1 ... January
echo    2 ... February
echo    3 ... March
echo    4 ... April
echo    5 ... May
echo    6 ... June
echo    7 ... July
echo    8 ... August
echo    9 ... September
echo    O ... October
echo    N ... November
echo    D ... December
echo(
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 123456789OND /N /M "Please select month:"
set "Month=%Errorlevel%"
for %%I in ("1 JAN" "2 FEB" "3 MAR" "4 APR" "5 MAY" "6 JUN" "7 JUL" "8 AUG" "9 SEP" "10 OCT" "11 NOV" "12 DEC") do for /F "tokens=1,2" %%J in (%%I) do if %%J == %Month% set "Month=%%K" & goto BuildFileName

:BuildFileName
echo Selected month: %Month%

endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `choice /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`